# Pull data from MySQL and add it to terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, mysql, terms

I need to do something above my knowledge base. Here's what I need to do:

Pulling data from a specific column, copy it to wp_terms table, make the relationship with the appropriate taxonomy and repeat this process automatically every week.
It is important that when repeating the process, only data that are not existing in wp_terms table should be copied. More clearly:

I have a table named wp_coins with thousands of cryptocurrencies:

| id | coin_id | name | symbol | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bitcoin | Bitcoin | BTC |  |
| 2 | ethereum | Ethereum | ETH |  |
| 3 | tether | Tether | USDT |  |

I created a custom taxonomy named 'coins' and I need to copy under it all data in 'symbol' column from wp_coins. Since new cryptocurrencies are added automatically to wp_coins, I need to check every week if we have new listing and if so, add it to wp_terms. I guess all the process should create the relationship with my custom taxonomy too.

I already know there is a few way to do it with plugins (export data with xls , filter it manually and import it etc) but checking manually new listings, filtering, etc will take a lot of time. So, if there is any MySQL or $wpdb way to do it, any help on this would be great. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is the `wp_coins` table in the same database as your WordPress data? I'd strongly recommend using [`wp_insert_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) to add data to `wp_terms`, and look into [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) to set up your weekly process.

Comment: Yes, it is. I will try this way, thanks a lot Pat.

Comment: One more function you'll probably find helpful: [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/). This will allow you to search the existing terms in the taxonomy (eg `get_term_by( 'name', $coin_title, 'my-coin-taxonomy' )`) to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Nice! thanks again Pat.